# Show Alert Message When Input Is Too Short using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display an alert message when the input is shorter than given limit, using jQuery. Unfortunately, my code isn't working, therefore, seeking your help.

Here are the codes I am using.

HTML

```
<input type="textarea" name="message" id="message" row="20" col="50" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("input:submit[name='submit']").on("click",function() {
        var msgwords = $("input:textarea[name='message']").val().replace( /[^\w ]/g, "" ).split( /\s+/ ).length;
        var minwords = 10;
            if (comwords < minwords) {
                alert("Your Comment is too short.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have `if( comwords < ...` but you have defined `msgwords`.

Comment: Do you get any errors?  Perhaps about `comwords` not being defined?

Comment: Also, `split()` is unnecessary. You can just check the length of the string.

Comment: @Abhik I have your code working as you need - see my answer, just reference the exact ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to switch `if(comwords < minwords)` to `if(msgwords < minwords)`

---

Here's your fully working code. Change as you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Use $ instead of `jQuery`, it's nicer */
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Reference the button ID (it's unique...) */
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        /* Your function to replace works nicely */
        var msgwords = $("#message").val().replace( /[^\w ]/g, "" ).split( /\s+/ ).length;
        var minwords = 10;
        if (msgwords < minwords) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Your Comment is too short.");
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

This code references the exact ID's (you can change this once you know it's working). Your split function checking for *words* instead of *characters* also works nicely. Finally, `e.preventDefault()` prevents the button from submitting if the comment is too short.

---

I'd also like to point out that you *could* use either `e.preventDefault();` or `return false`, with the latter being the equivalent of `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();`. This prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up") the DOM.

Comment: For usage of `.submit()` and a calculation of the real number of matches for an empty string see my answer ;)

Comment: Is that what OP asked for? That's fine, let him choose which ever :)

Comment: Aweosme!! Working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

1. There's no such `:textarea` pseudo-selector.
2. `comwords` is not defined.

You can drop `:textarea` from the selector anyways. And use `msgwords` instead of `comwords`.

---

I would do instead:

- Use `.form()` to bind to the `submit` event. Plus, preventing the form submission.
- Clean up leading and trailing spaces using `String#trim`.
- Make use of the `id` attribute of your elements ;)

Along these lines:

```
<form>
  <input type="textarea" name="message" id="message" row="20" col="50" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("form").submit(function () {
    var minwords = 10;
    /* Trim leading and trailing spaces */
    var message = $("#message").val().trim();
    var words = message.split(/\s+/).length;
    /* Disambiguous matches for an empty string  */
    if ((message == "") || (words < minwords)) {
      alert("Your comment is too short.");
      /* Prevent form submission by returning false */
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 great example. As I hate alert boxes maybe you could show him how to append the error and refocus on the invalid input. Just a thought